# How to implement a 2D vector of enum class objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

This is the enum class I use.

```
enum class PlayerColor {BLACK, BLUE, RED};
```

This is how I want to create a vector. Basically, store a vertex name along with its color.
I am getting plenty of errors.

```
typedef pair<int, PlayerColor> ip;

vector< vector< ip > > vertices;
```

This is how I want to initialize the 2D vector (inside a constructor)

```
for(auto i=vertices.begin()+1;i<vertices.end();++i)
    for(auto j=i->begin()+1;j<i->end();++j)
    {
        *(j.first)=c++;   //error
        *(j.second)=PlayerColor::BLACK;  //error
    }
```

This function takes the names of two vertices and adds an edge between them. (Routine works fine otherwise)

```
addEdge(vertices[i][j+1].first,vertices[i][j].first); //error
```

EDIT:
`addEdge` function is defined as:

```
void HexBoard::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    edge[u].push_back(v);
    edge[v].push_back(u);
}
```

`edge` is :

```
vector< vector<int> > edge;
```

It is initialized in C++11 style as:

```
edge(vector< vector<int> > (size*size + 1 + 4)),EAST(size*size+1),WEST(size*size+2)
```

`size` is an integer.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @anjruu 
Plenty of errors on this line

'*(j.first)=c++;'
and this one:
'addEdge(vertices[i][j+1].first,vertices[i][j].first);'

Comment: could you please shed some light on what **is** `c` and on the definition of `addEdge`

Comment: j is an iterator, so I'm not shocked by that at all. try `j->first = c++;` etc. And you should also note that firing those loops with that automatic addition to `begin()` without knowing if the vector is empty or not is inherently dangerous. And since you conveniently decided to "tell" us about `addEdge` rather than "show" it to us, i have no comment on that whatsoever.

Comment: @WhozCraig, @IvayloStrandjev - 

`c` is an integer.

The definition of addEdge is:

`void HexBoard::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    edge[u].push_back(v);
    edge[v].push_back(u);
}`

**edge is a 2D int vector**
`vector< vector<int> > edge;`

**It is initialized by the following initializer list.**
`edge(vector< vector<int> > (size*size + 1 + 4)),EAST(size*size+1),WEST(size*size+2)`

Yes, `j->first` is what it should have been. I still can't get the `addEdge` function call working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error i see is in the expressions `*(j.first)=c++;` and `*(j.second)=PlayerColor::BLACK;`
you need to dereference the iterator `j` like such:

```
    (*j).first=c++;   //no error
    (*j).second = PlayerColor::BLACK;  //no error
```

Edit:

The other errors are probably because your code does't declare things correctly like in the line:

`addEdge(vertices[i][j+1].first,vertices[i][j].first);`

there is no error here if `i` and `j` are of integer types. If `i` and `j` are iterators then you will get an error.

Comment: Or, more synthetically, use the `->` operator.

Comment: The `addEdge()` function call does not work as well. It gives a `no matching function call error.` What could be the possible reasons?

`i` and `j` are `int` types

Comment: I can see from the code that you have `HexBoard::addEdge` you need to have a variable of type `HexBoard` to use it like such: `HexBoard x; x.addEdge(...)`